# Python iterating list of dates

Tags: python, list, function, loops, iterable

I have 10 years data with one file for each day. Each file has a name like this:

PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmD2_20151226_bil.bil (December 26, 2015)

I want to go through each file in and put the ones with the same date but different years on a list together so there should 365 lists with 10 items each. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this to work if anyone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Take the file name (minus bil suffix) and split on `_`, then assuming all file names are formatted consistently, take the 5th item and convert it to a date using the datetime module. As you parse the file names, add them to a list of elements containing the parsed datetime object and filename and then use the `itertools.groupby` function, with an appropriate key function to create the groups. As you haven't shown any attempts at your task, I doubt if you'll get anyone writing the code for you, but if you have made any attempts, posting them would help your cause.

Comment: consider accepting the answer pls  if it did help you, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reg exps to catch the date and then process it using `[]` operator of strings. For your sample filename the date can be caught by simple [0-9]{8} regular expression (it means "numeric character exactly 8 times).
Sample code for you:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'[0-9]{8}', fileName)
date = match.group()
year = date[:4]
```